# Should i close mysql connection in websocket

Tags: mysql, socket.io

in short words, i'm creating a chat service with socket.io and i was wondering if i should close mysql connection and then reopen when i have to use it. This chat service will probably receive 10-20 events per second.

I'm creating the connection outside of the socket:

```js
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'dbname',
})
```

and only used to run queries when a socket event is triggered

```js
socket.on('check_token', (token) => {
    // token is verified safely, not passing it as it is.
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE token = '" + token + "'", (error, results, fields) => {...})
})
```

But, should i close the connection after my job is done to free mysql?
Or, does closing the connection and re-connecting makes it worse since it will alwas reconnect when an event is triggered.
Or.. is there a better way that i don't know of?

Comment: You should always close and reopen JDBC connections, and use an underlying connection pool.

Comment: Qestion is not about JDBC

Comment: The "enterprise" solution is to use a "connection pool", which is collection of connections, many of which stay open. This offers some additional redundancy in case one of the connections is unexpectedly closed, and allows simultaneous queries. It is overkill for an app with low to medium usage, where simply leaving the db connection open and reusing it is sufficient. An alternative approach for enterprise-scale is to load-balance multiple apps instead of using a connection pool, so using a single connection that stays open is also viable in that scenario.

Comment: @Codebling thanks, I wasn't aware of connection pools at the time. With Antek's answer I've replaced my connection with connection pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Establishing connection to database takes long time.
You should not disconnect from db after job is done.
Application server should use connection pool.
Start your pool when your server starts, with eg 10 concurrent connections.
Pool size (connections quantity) depends on your system load. Sometimes you need 2 concurrent connections, and sometimes 100.
When you want to get data from db, simply obtain connection from pool, and return it when it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to keep a single connection or a group of persistent database connections open. The overhead of establishing a connection every single request would otherwise give you lots of overall application latency.

Keeping connections open still requires keeping track of them to release resources early upon dead connections, disconnected peers, etc.